# MySQL user data storage

Tags: mysql

I have two tables that should somehow be associated. Let's call them `table_a` and 
`table_b`. A row in `table_a` can be associated with multiple rows in `table_b`, and the same goes the other way around. How could I achieve this? Should I use a pivot table?

Both tables have an auto-incrementing `id`-column.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're looking for is called a many-to-many relationship (a given user has zero or more games, a given game has zero or more users).  This is typically handled with a "mapping table", e.g. USER_GAMES which has a user_id and a game_id, uniqueness is on the combination of these.  http://www.joinfu.com/2005/12/managing-many-to-many-relationships-in-mysql-part-1/ has some good details.

Comment: Thanks! Then I'll go with that.

Comment: No problem.  For added robustness, ensure USER_GAMES (or whatever you decide to call it) has appropriate foreign keys to user and game tables' primary keys.

Answer (score 1):

As it is a many to many relationship, an intersection table with the user ID & game ID would be the best.   Otherwise you would have to parse the list of game ID's stored in the user table and that would cause performance issues.